# Applications of Complex Analysis.

Tags: complex-analysis

I am wondering which fields of science, and which professional positions would make regular or semi-regular use of the techniques of complex analysis.

Comment: Laplace transforms are used in engineering, they produce the transfer functions of a mechanical system, whose poles and zeros and phase have  physical meaning, but I doubt techniques from complex analysis is being used regularly.

Comment: Briefly, any of the branches of physics and chemistry which use quantum mechanics and the parts of electrical engineering that involve electronics.  It is simply a convenient language in which to express quantities and make calculations.  (And by "making use of techniques", I mean that the specialists are by-and-large rather "unrigorous"...)

Comment: Aerodynamics: when simulating lift on a wing, this involves evaluating contour integral a and performing conformal transformations. See for example: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kutta–Joukowski_theorem